# Search autocomplete plugin

Tags: search, autocomplete, asp.net

Looking for an ASP.NET plugin I can integrate with our company website (www.rackattack.com) that would show suggestions as you type in the search box.

Something simple, easy, cheap/free.

Answer (score 1):

The Syncfusion [AutoComplete](http://asp.syncfusion.com/demos/web/autocomplete/databinding-remote.aspx) control can be used for displaying a list of suggestions from a database.

The whole product is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify.

Note: I work for Syncfusion.